# Print first n odd numbers in APL

Tags: apl

I just started exploring APL. Though, familiar with C++ and python, I got stuck executing a simple program 'Print first n odd numbers' where n is the input in APL.
Please help APL coders.

Comment: Could you post some code, please?

Answer (score 6):

You mean you got stuck *implementing* that APL program?

Mathematically, odd numbers are of the form 2i+1.  In APL the expression `⍳n` gives us the integers `0` through `n-1` (assuming index origin 0).  To obtain the desired result, multiply those by two and add one:

```
1+2×⍳n
```